# How to transform a group of text to a list with regex

Tags: r, regex

I have to transform all the arguments in a text character vector into an easy-to-reference format: A list that has 3 column (presenter, time and text) by using R.

For example, presenter should be

```
# HARPER'S
```

time should be

```
# [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]
```

and text should be the rest in the argument.

I need to calculate the number of arguments in the text (each start of

```
# HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]
```

is an argument). I want to Create a new list object named 'arguments' and each element of the list is a sublist that contains three elements ('presenter', 'time' and 'text').

Then extract the presenter name and time into two character vectors (also remove indentation), and leave the 'presenter' element and 'time' element in the sublist for that argument.

```
This is the text: 
 [1] "HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]:  When the computer was young, the word hacking was"  
  [2] "used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the"    
  [3] "uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a"   
  [4] "\"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark"  
  [5] "connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic,"   
  [6] "and does it survive?"                                                             
  [7] ""                                                                                 
  [8] "ADELAIDE [Day 1, 9:25 A.M.]:  the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud.  It"  
  [9] "survives in anyone excited by technology's power to turn many small,"             
 [10] "insignificant things into one vast, beautiful thing.  It is a fraud because"      
 [11] "there is nothing magical about computers that causes a user to undergo"           
 [12] "religious conversion and devote himself to the public good.  Early automobile"    
 [13] "inventors were hackers too.  At first the elite drove in luxury.  Later"          
 [14] "practically everyone had a car.  Now we have traffic jams, drunk drivers, air"    
 [15] "pollution, and suburban sprawl.  The old magic of an automobile occasionally"     
 [16] "surfaces, but we possess no delusions that it automatically invades the"          
 [17] "consciousness of anyone who sits behind the wheel.  Computers are power, and"     
 [18] "direct contact with power can bring out the best or worst in a person.  It's"     
 [19] "tempting to think that everyone exposed to the technology will be grandly"        
 [20] "inspired, but, alas, it just ain't so."                                           
 [21] ""                                                                                 
 [22] "BRAND [Day 1, 9:54 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic involves several things.  One is"     
 [23] "avoiding waste; insisting on using idle computer power -- often hacking into a"   
 [24] "system to do so, while taking the greatest precautions not to damage the"         
 [25] "system.  A second goal of many hackers is the free exchange of  technical"        
 [26] "information.  These hackers feel that patent and copyright restrictions slow"     
 [27] "down technological advances.  A third goal is the advancement of human"           
 [28] "knowledge for its own sake.  Often this approach is unconventional.  People we"   
 [29] "call crackers often explore systems and do mischief.  The are called hackers by"  
 [30] "the press, which doesn't understand the issues."                                  
 [31] ""                                                                                 
 [32] "KK [Day 1, 11:19 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on because the"    
 [33] "explorations of basement tinkerers were very local.  Once we all became"          
 [34] "connected, the work of these investigations rippled through the world.  today"    
 [35] "the hacking spirit is alive and kicking in video, satellite TV, and radio.  In"   
 [36] "some fields they are called chippers, because the modify and peddle altered"      
 [37] "chips.  Everything that was once said about \"phone phreaks\" can be said about"  
 [38] "them too."
```

I have tried to calculate the length of the argument.

```
length(grep("^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)", text_data))
arguments = list(presenters = regmatches(text_data, regexpr("^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)", text_data)), time = regmatches(text_data, regexpr("(\\[.*\\])", text_data)), text =  regmatches(paste(unlist(text_data), collapse =" ")), regexpr("(:\\s.*)", regmatches(paste(unlist(text_data), collapse =" "))))
text_data
```

The length of the list "arguments" should be 55.

An example of the output for the first argument would be

```
$presenter
[1] "HARPER'S"

$time
[1] "[Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]"

$text
[1] ":  When the computer was young, the word hacking was used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a \"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic, and does it survive?"
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Try `library(stringr)` and  `str_match(paste(lines, collapse="\n"), "(?sm)^([A-Z]+(?:'[A-Z]+)?)\\s+(\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]):\\s*(.*?)(?=\n{2}|\\z)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the comment. I tried this and only works with the first argument.

Comment: Use `str_match_all`, I forgot I pasted the contents.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I used it and it works. Is there anyways to name the column after ``str_match_all``? And maybe subset the column after? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you assign the `str_match_all` results to `data` variable, you may use  `presenterCol <- data[[1]][,2]`,  `timeCol <- data[[1]][,3]`, `textCol <- data[[1]][,4]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much! This solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
library(stringr)
data <- str_match(paste(lines, collapse="\n"), "(?sm)^([A-Z]+(?:'[A-Z]+)?)\\s+(\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]):\\s*(.*?)(?=\n{2}|\\z)")
presenterCol <- data[[1]][,2]
timeCol <- data[[1]][,3]
textCol <- data[[1]][,4]
```

The point here is that lines are joined with a newline char using `paste(lines, collapse="\n")` so that we could run a regex on a single multiline string, to grab 1) presenter details at the start, 2) date inside square brackets and 3) the rest of text up to a blank line or end of the whole string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtHnEk/1).

**Regex details**

- `(?sm)` - `s` modifier makes `.` match newlines, and `m` makes `^` match start of lines
- `^` - start of a line
- `([A-Z]+(?:'[A-Z]+)?)` - Group 1: 1+ uppercase letters and then an optional sequence of `'` and 1+ uppercase letters
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\])` - Group 2: `[`, 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
- `:` - a colon
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `(?=\n{2}|\\z)` - (a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location) two newlines or the end of the whole string.